# EF Core Foreign Key via Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have a 2 classes:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
public class ItemStats //inhenrit from Item
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MaxEnhanceLevel { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

This is a TPT but since it's not supported out of the box I can't use inheritance. I know how to achieve this using data annotation

```
 [ForeignKey(nameof(Item))]
 public int Id { get; set; }
```

But how can I do this via FluentAPI? I don't want data annotation in my Entitie Classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a [One-to-one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#one-to-one) relationship with [single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#single-navigation-property-1), principal entity `Item` and dependent entity `ItemStats`, using the so called [shared primary key association](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations), where the dependent entity PK is also a FK to the principal entity.

Fluent API for one-to-one relationships are `HasOne`, `WithOne`, `HasForeignKey` and `HasPrincipalKey`. Please note that the generic type arguments to `HasForeignKey` and `HasPrincipalKey` (which normally are omitted for one-to-many relationship) here are important because they indentify which entity is principal and which - dependent.

With that being said, the fluent configuration for your model is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ItemStats>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Item)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ItemStats>(e => e.Id);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying modelBuilder.Entity<ItemStats>().HasOne(i => i.Item).WithOne().HasForeignKey("Item"); and It wasn't working. Can you explain what this code was doing? ty in advance.

Comment: Well, it's telling EF that (1) `ItemStats` has one `Item` with navigation property `ItemStats.Item`, (2) `Item` has one `ItemStats` without navigation property, (3) `ItemStats` is the dependent and uses the PK property `Id` as foreign key (instead of separate property).